# How do I specify an option for git clone when using git plug in for Hudson?

Tags: hudson-plugins

I'm using Hudson with git plug in to run my automation tests.  I want to specify an option when it runs git clone (eg. git clone --depth 1) to speed up the process.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is now exposed as a checkable option in Jenkins: "Shallow Clone".

Answer (score 0):

Currently it seems that there is no direct support for this.

There is a bugtracker for this request on the Jenkins JIRA site: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4418

You can 'upvote' the request there.  It was initially closed as "won't fix," but currently (April 2013) has a status of 'Reopened.'